# java.lang.ClassCastException and java.lang.AssertionError while running nodetool cleanup

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

I am using cassandra-2.0.3, I have added a new node in datacenter (using vnodes) but while running nodetool cleanup i am getting

```
Error occurred during cleanup
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$EmptyCompactionScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.performAllSSTableOperation(CompactionManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.performCleanup(CompactionManager.java:265)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.forceCleanup(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1054)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.forceKeyspaceCleanup(StorageService.java:2038)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$EmptyCompactionScanner cannot be cast to org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableScanner
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.doCleanupCompaction(CompactionManager.java:563)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.access$400(CompactionManager.java:62)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$5.perform(CompactionManager.java:274)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$2.call(CompactionManager.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    ... 3 more
```

After some time I tried it to run again and its end up with java.lang.AssertionError.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: [SSTableReader(path='/home/test/cassandra/data/Emails-jb-6-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/home/test/cassandra/data/Emails-jb-5-Data.db'), SSTableReader(path='/home/test/cassandra/data/Emails-jb-4-Data.db')]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$12.call(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2054)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$12.call(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2051)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2033)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.markAllCompacting(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2064)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.performAllSSTableOperation(CompactionManager.java:214)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager.performCleanup(CompactionManager.java:265)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.forceCleanup(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1054)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.forceKeyspaceCleanup(StorageService.java:2038)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

what are the cause for the above exceptions? Any quick solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The ClassCastException looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6462 which was fixed in 2.0.4.

I would suggest upgrading to the latest version and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

The Docs say, "Use this (nodetool cleanup) command to remove unwanted data after adding a new node to the cluster."

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCleanup.html

Comment: And what "command" is that?  Please provide some additional details in case the link ever goes stale.

Comment: But the procedure listed in this documentation directly states that after adding a new node we have to run cleanup.
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

Comment: Is it needed to run cleanup after running repair? because after running nodetool repair my DCs are looking well balanced.